# "dig cloudapp.net" (the main MS Azure domain) returns nothing, is this allowed in DNS?

Tags: azure, dns, dig

The domain "cloudapp.net" is used by Microsoft's Azure service. I ran a `dig cloudapp.net` command and to my surprise this yielded nothing (no ANSWER section came back in the response). "cloudapp.net" is a main domain in use by Microsoft's Azure service and Azure customers leverage it by having a subdomain off it such as "yourwebsite.cloudapp.net" and using a CNAME to link their branded domain to their sire hosted on the Azure service.

How can you have a domain name "cloudapp.net" that points to nothing basically? It is not required in DNS for a second-level domain to have an IP address linked to it? What would be some reasons for configuring your domain name in such a way? Why not have "cloudapp.net" by default point to the main MS site? Just wanting to understand why this is allowed in DNS and why from a technical perspective a company would choose to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't actually return 'nothing', if you run `dig cloudapp.net IN ANY`, you'll see you've been given a list of nameservers, which a recursive dns resolver will follow for more details, or so can you:

`dig sub.cloudapp.net IN ANY @prd1.azuredns-cloud.net`

thus, cloudapp.net doesn't need to have a host address record (and isn't required one), a request for a subdomain will still query the main nameservers, which will return a host record for a valid subdomain, or `NXDOMAIN` if not.

*its possible there is an internal or security reason they don't want to point cloudapp.net to a website; perhaps ensure customer flow through one portal. just a hypothesis*